# How to remove whitespace between numbers only?

Tags: regex, powershell, rename

I have a bunch of directories named differently like this:

```
firstname lastname (123) 456 7890
firstname lastname (234) 567-8910
firstname lastname 345-678-9101
```

I'm trying to rename each directory to keep the name with a space but have no spaces between the numbers like this:

```
firstname lastname 1234567890
firstname lastname 2345678910
firstname lastname 3456789101
```

This is what I have going right now:

```
$destination = "D:\test"

Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse -Directory |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '[()\s-]',''} -Verbose

##output##
firstnamelastname1234567890
firstnamelastname2345678910
firstnamelastname3456789101
```

This kind of works but doesn't leave a space between the firstname lastname and phone number. I've been trying other regex patterns but can't find a solution to target numbers. Is there a way to target the whitespace between only numbers?

Comment: You can use a regex like this `(?<=\d|\))[- ](?=\d)` https://regex101.com/r/4YR8ft/1 Actually.. it looks like you want to remove the parens too, so a little more work is needed. But the point is you can use lookahead/lookbehinds.

Comment: The regex above will only match `-` and `space`, not the parentheses.  If that doesn't work for you, you can try this: `(?<=\d)[()\s-]|[()\s-](?=\d)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
$_.name -replace '[^\w\s]*(\d+)\W*(?=[\d\W]*$)', '$1'
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5cw%5cs%5d*%28%5cd%2b%29%5cW*%28%3f%3d%5b%5cd%5cW%5d*%24%29&i=firstname+lastname+%28123%29+456+7890%0d%0afirstname+lastname+%28234%29+567-8910%0d%0afirstname+lastname+345-678-9101&r=%241&o=m)

**Details**

- `[^\w\s]*` - any zero or more chars other than word and whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `\W*` - any zero or more non-word chars...
- `(?=[\d\W]*$)` - that are immediately followed with zero or more non-word or digit chars up to the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Wiktor Stribiżew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65173125/45375) with **a solution that is perhaps easier to conceptualize**:

```bash
@(
  'firstname lastname (123) 456-7890', 
  'firstname lastname (234) 567-8910',
  'firstname lastname 345-678-9101'
) | ForEach-Object {
  # Split into the first and second space-separated token, 
  # and whatever tokens remain.
  $first, $second, $rest = $_ -split ' ', 3
  # Re-join the tokens with spaces, removing all non-digit chars.
  # from  whatever remained, and output the result.
  $first, $second, ($rest -replace '\D') -join ' '
}
```

This yields the following, as intended:

```
firstname lastname 1234567890
firstname lastname 2345678910
firstname lastname 3456789101
```

- `$first, $second, $rest = $_ -split ' ', 3` uses `-split`, the [string-splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), to split each input string into *at most 3* space-separated tokens; that is, whatever follows the *second* space - even if it contains spaces -  becomes the *third* - and by definition *last* - array element.
- `$rest -replace '\D'` uses `-replace`, the [regular-expression-based string replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), to remove all *non-digit* (`\D`) characters from whatever part of the string that follows the second space-separated token (`$rest`).
- `-join`, the [string-joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join), is used to re-join the resulting tokens with spaces, and the resulting string is output to the pipeline.